# IE 9 is blowing up my design

Tags: wordpress, html, internet-explorer-9

So I'm a little bit of a loss as to why this is happening, but my site that looks OK across all other (modern) browsers (haven't yet had time to code for older browsers) is completely destroyed in Internet Explorer 9. Is there some well-known bug I'm just not aware of?

EDIT: Wow, holy crap, I'm dumb. Forgot the link. http://fdtonline.net/blog

Comment: Is IE9 running in standards mode?

Comment: @MarcB: You won't do that if your client is paying you a ton for IE support.

Comment: There are many well-known bugs and issues that lead to cross-browser compatibility problems. We can provide better information about your specific issue if you post your code, describe the problem in detail, and (optionally, but helpful) post your work online so we can test it.

Comment: IE is known to render things differently than other major browsers.  Without your specific site it'd be hard to say why you are getting issues.  First step is check your doctype, and any meta headers.  Post at minimum that information, if you can narrow it down to a simple example of the differences you should post that.

Comment: No one can help unless you edit your question and add the site URL so people can see some code.

Comment: Hey, IE 9 is kind of a modern browser, but still it doesn't have a full implementation of HTML5 and CSS3. Can you describe exactly your problem. What kind are the differences and are they from some kind of not implemented in IE CSS3 attribute? Give us some details, so we could assist.

Comment: DUMPING IE IS NOT A SOLUTION! Help him instead!

Comment: If you think dumping a browser is a solution, you don't know what web is about.

Answer (score 0):

None of your Javascript is working. You get a syntax error at the end of the first script block, and as the object in that block is not created, nothing else works after that.

You have mismatching comment tags inside the script tags. Remove the `<!--` at the start of your script blocks.

Comments inside scripts blocks were only needed to keep scripts showing up in browsers that didn't know what scripts was. You don't have to worry about those. I don't think that any  browsers from that era are even possible to run on todays computers.

Answer (score 0):

Added after EDIT 2,3:

You have stuff declared directly in the  tag. Load those in the  instead.
Also this structure:

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Won't load the  open tag if the browser is different than IE.

Added after EDIT 1:

It looks like your *wrapper* is somehow commented or deleted 'cos it isn't loaded at all in the DOM in IE.

To DEBUG in IE just press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
Also, here are some notes:

**To center the main content use**:

```
text-align: center;
```

On the parent and

```
margin-left: 20px auto;
```

On the child.

Additionally i think that there are lots of mistakes in your javascript. IE also have an error console. Take a look at it.

P.S. I'll edit and update this post while I gradually search and find different mistakes.

Comment: I have to go now. I'll add more as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you have a number of conditional IE tags before the `<html>` tag.  Some are even between the `<html>` and `<head>` tags. Try moving those IE conditional into the `<head>`.  That will get you started towards making IE behave more like you'd expect.  When I am concerned about IE as you are, I also do my best to have 100% valid code - put that thing through a through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.fdtonline.net/blog/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).